# Generating function for $a_n=n$, $n\ge0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions

> Given the sequence $a_n$ where $a_n=n$ in every $n\ge0$. Find the generating function of $a_n$.

Of course this means the generating function is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n$. But how to simplify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Consider $g'(x)$ for $g(x)=1+x+x^2+\cdots$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\right)
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^n 1\right)x^n
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)x^n.
$$

Hence
$$
\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n.
$$